Find the 16th image
Here are the 2nd and 3rd images in a sequence:


What household appliance is shown in the 16th image?

The household appliance would be

 A Hoover vacuum cleaner.

Because the sequence is

 homonyms of US presidents in reverse order.

The "second" one

 Is a trump (slang for flatulence), which is spelled the same as Trump, the 2nd most recent president.

The "third" one

 Is an Obama, spelled the same as Obama, the 3rd most recent president.

So the sixteenth one

 Would be a Hoover vacuum cleaner, corresponding to Herbert Hoover, the 16th most recent president.

